# Почему переноситься строка в браузере и как убрать перенос? HTML

Tags: html

```
<div id="board_price">
  <span class="price_title" style="padding-left:1px; font-size:18px">{$LANG.PRICE}: </span>
     {if $item.price} 
        {$item.price} <p align="left">руб.</p>
     {else}
       {$LANG.PRICE_CONTRACT}
     {/if}    
</div>
```

Должно быть в браузере Цена: например 100 руб. слово руб. уходит на следующую строку. Подскажите.

Comment: Проблему решил сам..

Comment: [-ТСЯ или -ТЬСЯ][1]   
ну правда глаз режет!
[1]: http://tsya.ru/

Comment: Всем спасибо проблема решена убрав лишние {if $item.price} {$item.price}

Answer (score 1):

```
<p align="left">руб.</p>
```

тег `<p>` это и есть новая строка.

http://htmlbook.ru/html/p

Используй например тот же `span`.